# C array of structs syntax error

Tags: c, syntax

Here is the piece of code that I am getting error, SDL_Rect's definition is copied over from documentation:

```
typedef struct{
  Sint16 x, y;
  Uint16 w, h;
} SDL_Rect;


SDL_Rect clips[4];

clips[0].x = 0;
clips[0].y = 0;
clips[0].w = 100;
clips[0].h = 100;
```

Here is how I am compiling it:

```
gcc -march=native -static-libgcc -o sprite sprite.c functions.o -L/usr/lib -lSDL -lpthread -lm -ldl -lpthread -lSDL_image
```

Here is the error that I am getting: `expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token` for each line of clips[..] . I have tried putting paranthesis around clips[..] but It didn't work either. This is plain "C" by the way. Not C++.

### Edit

I have copied over SDL_Rect here from SDL's documentation in order to show what it was. It is not actually in the source file I am using. Therefore, missing of the semicolon cannot be the issue. And this code is in the global scope.

Comment: Are you writing this at file scope?

Comment: Yes. This is at file scope. Also, read my edit please :)

Comment: You cannot have assignment statements at file scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This (-initialisation-) assignment is at global scope which is not possible.

It is possible to initialise the array:

```
SDL_Rect clips[4] = {
                        { 0, 0, 100, 100 }, /* Element 0 initial values */
                        { 1, 1, 200, 200 }  /* Element 1 initial values */
                                            /* Element 2 and 3 unspecified so
                                               zero initialised. */
                    };
```

If C99 compliant compiler you can explicitly state the variables being initialised:

```
SDL_Rect clips[4] = {
                        { .x = 0, .y = 0, .w = 100, .h = 100 }
                    };
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. How can we be sure which is x,y etc. like this though?

Comment: It will be the order in which the variables are declared. I think C99 introducted a new syntax that allowed the variables to be explicitly stated. Is your compiler C99 compliant?

Comment: @yasar11732: You can write the it as `{ .x = 0, .y = 0, .w = 100, .h = 100 }` etc (In C99).

Comment: I am using latest gcc. I think it should be.

Comment: @sth, thanks for confirming C99 feature. yasar11732, this should be available to you with latest gcc, I tested it [here](http://ideone.com/0oCCW) which used gcc 4.3.4.

Answer (score 1):

Missing a ; after the SDL_Rect:

`typedef struct{
  Sint16 x, y;
  Uint16 w, h;
} SDL_Rect;`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a ; after SDL_Rect in your struct definition.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
typedef struct{
Sint16 x, y;
Uint16 w, h;
} SDL_Rect;
```

Notice the **semicolon** at the end.

Answer (score 0):

There miss the semicolon at the end of the structure:

```
typedef struct{
  Sint16 x, y;
  Uint16 w, h;
} SDL_Rect;
```